# How to locate Perl modules in the same directory as the script

Tags: perl, module, cgi

Now that recent versions of Perl have removed "." from @INC, I'm curious about best practices for module file location. Until now, the *.pm files associated with each application on our web site were in the same directory as the scripts. This, I gather, creates a security vulnerability.

We don't have write access to the remaining directories in @INC.

We could just leave the pm files where they are, and add `use lib ".";` to all our existing scripts, but wouldn't this just preserve the security vulnerability?

Any suggestions on how our Perl scripts and their associated modules can be best organized in the light of this new development?

Comment: `.` is not where the script is located, that's `$FindBin::Bin`. `.` is from where the script was called.

Comment: @choroba, Using `$FindBin::RealBin` instead of `$FindBin::Bin` given free support for symlinks to your executable.

Comment: @Quentin, Nonsense! First of all, If you use Plack, you might still be using CGI or Fast CGI, so it's not an alternative to CGI at all! And secondly, unless you're saying Plack adds the handler's file's path to `@INC` -- and I doubt you are -- it wouldn't help at all! For all we know, the OP is using Plack, so your comment is not constructive or useful at all.

Answer (score 2):

No, placing modules in the same directory as the script isn't a security vulnerability. Assuming the current work directory (`.`) is the script's directory is a bug and a security vulnerability.

`.` was never guaranteed to be the directory in which the script is located. (In fact, time and time again, people have found `.` to be `/` in CGI scripts.) Just keep using what you should already be using:

```
 use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
 use lib $RealBin;
```

Comment: (I'm disappointed they didn't make paths in `@INC` relative to `$RealBin` instead of removing `.`. It would have solved the problem and fixed buggy code that relied on `.` and buggy code that add relative paths to `@INC`.)

Comment: Perldoc says "If there are two modules using FindBin from different directories under the same interpreter, this won't work." Does that apply to two or more instances of Apache running concurrently? Surely not.

Comment: "*This is a problem under mod_perl and other persistent Perl environments, where you shouldn't use this module. Which also means that you should avoid using `FindBin` in modules that you plan to put on CPAN. To make sure that `FindBin` will work is to call the `again` function*" ... If you have a CGI script, the concern does not apply. If you are running the script under `mod_perl` then you must care.

Comment: @Peter P, FindBin populates `$RealBin` and such from `$0` when it is first loaded. So if you use the same `perl` process to execute multiple scripts, you need to set `$0` and call `FindBin::again` to reinitialize `$RealBin`. For example, a Fast CGI worker might execute `local $0 = $script_fqfn; FindBin::again(); do($0);`.

Comment: *"I'm disappointed they didn't make paths in `@INC` relative to `$RealBin`"* Do you mean *relative* paths in `@INC`? Surely you don't want absolute paths disallowed? And `.` would have to be removed either way.

Comment: Yes, I meant relative paths. And no, `.` would not have to be removed. The problem with `.` is that you could trick a script (that might be running as root) to load a module from a dir you control rather than the script's dir.

Comment: I understand why `.` is a problem, but I don't get why it would be safe to leave it in `@INC`. It's an absolute path, so perl will still search the current working directory, which is something you don't want.

Comment: @Borodin, In unix, a path is absolute iff it starts with `/`, so `.` is not an absolute path. Therefore, it refers to the directory by that name in the CWD. And therefore, under the model I envisioned, `.` in `@INC` would be the same as `$RealBin/.`, which is just `$RealBin`.

Comment: @ikegami: Understood. Thanks. That's bizarre actually; without ever thinking about it I have had the idea that `..` is relative, and `.` in `/path/to/.` is relative, but `.` on its own is a magic label for the absolute current working directory, like `~` (in fact *exactly* like `~+/`). That's complete nonsense now that I consider my assumptions. Just shows how a lot can be built on basic misconceptions.

Comment: @Borodin, `.` is a little special in Windows, but only insofar as it works even if the directory doesn't actually contain a `.` entry, such as root directories.

Comment: @ikegami: Thank you. I didn't know *insofar* was a US word as well. I will start using it again now!

Comment: @Borodin, Blasphemy! I'm not an American; I'm Canadian! It's not commonly used, but it's definitely an acceptable word.

Comment: @ikegami: OP is Canadian also - shall we take over the world one line of code at a time?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to [FindBin](https://metacpan.org/pod/FindBin) is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename qw( dirname );
use File::Spec::Functions qw( rel2abs );

use lib rel2abs( dirname(__FILE__) );

print "$_\n" for @INC;
```

As @ikegami points out, if you want to be able to invoke the script via symlinks, you'll need:

```
use Cwd qw( abs_path );
use lib dirname(abs_path($0));
```

Comment: Not quite. This won't work if the script is launched via a symlink to the script. The following would be equivalent `use Cwd qw( abs_path ); use File::Basename qw( dirname ); use lib dirname(abs_path($0));`

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for reminding me that. I have `Options -FollowSymLinks` in my Apache configs, so it slips my mind.

Comment: The question isn't really Apache- or CGI-specific even though that might be what the OP is using.