# LoadRunner Web Tours cannot locate systemPaths

Tags: perl, loadrunner

Having problems setting up LoadRunner Web Tours. Getting the following error in error.log.

> Can't locate systemPaths in @INC (@INC contains:
>   C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib
>   C:/strawberry/perl/lib) at C:/WebTours/cgi-bin/welcome.pl line 16.,
>   referer: http://localhost:8080/WebTours/

I have setup those links in Env Variable Paths. systemPaths is not a file in there. In the welcome.pl, there is "require "systemPaths";" line, I do not know perl. Thanks

Comment: See [How to locate Perl modules in the same directory as the script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43738235/5899240)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[I'm assuming `C:\WebTours\cgi-bin\systemPaths.pm` exists.]*

Add the following to `C:\WebTours\cgi-bin\welcome.pl`:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
```

The module search path (`@INC`) used to include the current work directory (`.`), that many scripts incorrectly used as a proxy for the directory in which the script resides. So `welcome.pl` was buggy, which became very apparent with recent versions of Perl.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I added your code in and to other pl files.

It is start up now but not working properly. With the following error codes:

dump() better written as CORE::dump(). dump() will no longer be available in Perl 5.30 at C:/WebTours/cgi-bin/reservations.pl line 90
Use of assignment to $[ is deprecated at C:/WebTours/cgi-bin/timelocal.pl
Undefined subroutine &main::startform called at C:/WebTours/cgi-bin/reservations.pl

Comment: Hi, I changed the dump and deleted $[ liines.

Two error still there:
"CGI::param called in list context from C:/WebTo
Undefined subroutine &main::startform called at"